# Razor MVC - Post a model object to a controller action when button is pressed

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-6.0

Within an ASP.NET Core 6 MVC web app with Razor pages, I have a view about a product gallery (in this case pharmacy items) and each item card in the gallery has a button "Add to basket". When this button is pressed, I would like to send the product item to the `AddToBasket` action of the `BasketController`. The application can be found [here](https://github.com/MaxHoefl/razor-pharmacy/tree/master).

In tutorials I have only seen it being solved with a `form`, collecting user input and binding that input to model properties to then submit it to a controller. I don't need to collect any user input, the item model object is already there in the view:

```
@model IEnumerable<Razor.Pharmacy.Domain.Entities.PharmacyItem>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        @foreach (var item in Model) {
            ...
            <a href="@Url.Action("AddToBasket", "Basket", new { customerId = 0, item = item })" class="btn btn-dark">Add To Basket</a>
            ...
        }
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the controller action

```
// BasketController.cs

public void AddToBasket(int customerId, PharmacyItem item)
{
    _basketService.AddItemToBasket(customerId, item);
}
```

However, when I now press the "Add to basket" link, I don't get the intended `item` model object in the controller action method but an object with the default values

```
 {Razor.Pharmacy.Domain.Entities.PharmacyItem}
    ItemId: 0
    Name: null
    Price: 0
    Quantity: 0
    RequiresPrescription: false
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: Hi @tenticon, I suggest you learn ASP.NET Core carefully that MVC and Razor Page are quite different structure. Besides, it is better for you to check do you use MVC default route template in Program.cs. And be sure the `AddToBasket` is declared with `[HttpGet]` instead of `[HttpPost]`. For the anchor link only can send Get request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The complex model cannot be serialized dynamically( You can F12 in the browser to check the generated url) in your scenario. You need specify the property like below:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("AddToBasket", "Basket", new { customerId = 0, ItemId = item.ItemId,Name=item.Name,Price=item.Price})" class="btn btn-dark">Add To Basket</a>
```